# difference between new and new[ ]

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

What is the difference between `int* arr = new int [5];` and `int* arr = new int();`?

Comment: Be aware of [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - the first *appears* to work for 5 `int`s, but it is actually completely illegal. You are just overwriting some random memory that happens to sit next to the single `int` that you created. If you need 5 `int`s, make sure you allocate space for all of them.

Comment: allocate array, and allocate a single object. I.e. `int *i = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))` and `int* iarr = (int*)calloc(100,sizeof(int))` in C. Please read some C++ book, like The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: This is pretty standard in C++. Have you looked at some simple use cases of the `new` operator, like [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)?

Comment: Consider `std::vector` for practical purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int* arr = new int [5];
```

The above allocates an array of 5 `int` without initialising them, and assigns it to the new variable `arr`. The array should be freed using `delete [] arr;`.

```
int* arr = new int();
```

The above allocates a single value-initialized `int`, and assigns it to the mis-named new variable `arr`. The memory should be freed using `delete arr;`.

Accessing out-of-bounds, or trying to free something the wrong way all causes [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), which means neither compiler nor runtime are under any requirements whatsoever.

As your program ends shortly thereafter, it's acceptable to leak those allocations to avoid the make-work. You should add a comment that you do so intentionally though.